# CancellationToken with Hangfire

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, hangfire

First of all, I decided to use Hangfire because it can run code in a different Windows service or in fact, on a different server. I could easily perform my tasks using `Task` class but my logic will be running 24/7 for a very long period until it's stopped by the user and I don't think tasks can handle this. That's why I'm using Hangfire. I'm open minded to different solutions. More specifically, my logic is monitoring stuff 24/7 using web sockets.

If you look at my code below, it has Run method which spawns a new bot in a BackgroundJob from Hangfire. The problem is that when I have to stop a specific bot (let's say "Bot 1"), it should somehow identify the bot which it currently doesn't.

Hangfire's documentation is incomplete or at least I don't understand how to do that from what's written. https://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/background-methods/using-cancellation-tokens.html

```cs
private UpdateSubscription _subscription;
private readonly CancellationTokenSource _cts = new CancellationTokenSource();

public async Task RunAsync(string botName)
{
    var jobId = BackgroundJob.Enqueue(() => StartAsync(botName, _cts.Token));
    await _cache.SetAsync($"bot_{botName.Replace(" ", "_")}", jobId);
}

public void Start(Bot bot, CancellationToken token)
{
    // heavy logic
    _subscription = _socketClient.SubscribeToKlineUpdates(bot.CryptoPair.Symbol, bot.TimeInterval.Interval /*KlineInterval.OneHour*/, async data =>
    {
        ... logic ...

        if (token.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            await _socketClient.Unsubscribe(_subscription);
        }
    }
}

public async Task StopAsync(string botName)
{
    var jobId = await _cache.GetAsync<string>($"bot_{botName.Replace(" ", "_")}");

    if (jobId == null)
        return;

    BackgroundJob.Delete(jobId);
}
```

**Edit:** BackgroundJob is returning the jobId as string but somehow `if (token.IsCancellationRequested)` is never triggered even after `BackgroundJob.Delete(jobId)` call.

I also used Redis to store the job id. Edited the code above too.

Comment: Is your Bot class somehow aware of the CancellationToken? Where are you anticipating calling your Stop method?

Comment: @Tieson T., I'm calling it from signalR Hub from the client side.

Comment: Oh, I see why you were asking me. When I used `RecurringJobs` (cron jobs), I could name the job with name. I usually named it with the bot name. `RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate(bot.Name, () => Algorithm(null, bot, isTesting), bot.TimeInterval.CronExpression, TimeZoneInfo.Local);`. However, I don't find that functionality for BackgroundJob.

Comment: Unfortunately, all the Delete method does is remove the job from the queue. It doesn't stop the processing of the job if it's already running.

Comment: @TiesonT., so I gotta run away from Hangfire in that case.

Comment: Actually, I may have misspoke. According to the author of Hangfire, ["BackgroundJob.Delete method will do both – remove a job and cancel it (if you are using cancellation tokens)"](https://discuss.hangfire.io/t/cancel-a-running-job/603/2). So, what you have should work, assuming you know the job ID to delete / cancel.

Comment: @TiesonT., that's right. I put `if (token.IsCancellationRequested)` condition in the beginning of the web socket event and it canceled the task but when I put it inside a nested if, it doesn't trigger it. I'm 100% sure that my nested `if` is executed.  Perhaps, `if (token.IsCancellationRequested)` is executed only once (when my nested `if` is false) and it never gets to true again? I have no idea.

Comment: CancellationTokenSource implements IDisposable, so I assume it's meant to used in a using block. I would try using that instead of a global instance and see if it helps.

Answer (score 3):

To cancel a Hangfire Job you don't have to provide your own CancellationToken. Instead the enqueued method you provide to Hangfire needs a parameter of that type. When enqueing a job through code you provide in that case the default `CancellationToken.None` and Hangfire takes care to provide the *real* token when the method is executed. Within your method you regulary ask the token for it's state and exit if desired.

To cancel a running job, Hangfire itself watches for two event to fire the provided token. Either the server gets a shutdown request (which will put the job into a new enqueued state to run again on next startup) or a job delete request.

Here are some code sketches:

```
// The method initiated from Hangfire Worker with special parameters
// for cancellationToken and context, filled by Hangfire.
public async Task MyJob(int someParameter, CancellationToken cancellationToken, PerformContext context)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
        Console.WriteLine($"Processing {i} in job {context.Job.Id}");
        await DoSomething(i, cancellationToken);
    }
}

private string EnqueueMyJob(int someParameter)
{
    // When enqueuing a job, just provide some default values for the *magic parameters*
    return jobClient.Enqueue<MyTaskClass>(task => task.MyJob(someParameter, CancellationToken.None, null));
}

private void CancelMyJob(string jobId)
{
    // If the job is currently running, the cancellation token will be set.
    jobClient.Delete(jobId);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently, I am utilizing Hangfire version 1.8.7. In this version, **jobClient.Delete(jobId)** was giving an error. To address this issue, I attempted to use the following code snippet:

```
BackgroundJobClient backgroundJobClient = new BackgroundJobClient();
backgroundJobClient.Delete(JobId);
```

Another method available is:

With **BackgroundJob.Delete(jobId)**, there is no need to instantiate the **BackgroundJobClient**.

```
BackgroundJob.Delete(jobId);
```

Comment: I am using 1.8.10, but can you pls provide why are we deleting? are you saying that instead of cancellation token, we can just use Delete methond?

Comment: In my case, some Hangfire calls are taking too much time or, you can say, they go into an infinite loop (which my coworkers assume). To address that issue, I was assigned the task to delete a specific job based on its job ID. According to my understanding, cancellation tokens delete all the processes that are executing in Hangfire after a specific time period (which we provide). Correct me if I am wrong.